# What is the private_info scope for?

Tags: discussion, documentation, api-v2.1

In the docs it says you can pass `private_info` for scope when authenticating a user.
What does this allow you to access, that you couldn't otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication#scope) says about `private_info`:

> access full history of a user's private actions on the site.

What this means right now (API 2.1) is that that scope is needed to use [the `/reputation-history/` paths](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/full-reputation-history):

> **Discussion** (of `/users/{id}/reputation-history/full`)
>
> Returns a user's full reputation history, including private events.
>
> This method requires an access_token, with a **scope containing "private_info"**.
>
> This method returns a list of reputation_history.

---

According to the docs, at least, no other paths require that scope.